# HTML not displaying submit button in the correct order

Tags: php, html, css

I just started a php sudoku solver program, where the main page has a form. Inside that form, a php include statements calls a function which draws the grid with the inputs that form the sudoku box. Below that in the HTML code, I put a input submit button. However, this is placed above the grid on the website, as shown http://shodor.org/~amalani/sudoku.php. Does anyone know why this is?

The main code is here

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sudoku Solver</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <form name='entry' method='POST' action='solve.php'>    
            <?php 
                include('grid.php');
            ?>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit!'></input>           
        </form>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is here

```
td{
    border:1px solid black;
}input[type=number]{
    border:none;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}.xborder{
    border-bottom:3px solid black;
}.bothborder{
    border-bottom:3px solid black;
    border-right:3px solid black;
}.yborder{
    border-right:3px solid black;
}
```

and the  grid drawer code is here

```
<?php 
    for ($x=1;$x<=9;$x++){
echo '

            <tr>';
        for ($y=1;$y<=9;$y++){
            $name=$x.''.$y;
            if(($y==3||$y==6)&&($x==3||$x==6)){
                echo "
            <td class='bothborder' ><input type='number' name='$name'></input></td>";
            }
            else if ($y==3||$y==6){
                echo "
                <td class='yborder' ><input type='number' name='$name'></input></td>";
            }
            else if ($x==3||$x==6){
                echo "
            <td class='xborder' ><input type='number' name='$name'></input></td>";
            }
            else{
                echo "

                <td><input type='number' name='$name'></input></td>";
            }
        }
echo '
            </tr>';
    }

    ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: try moving the input field out of the form tag. in fact, move both the php script and the input tags out of the form tag.

Comment: `<form>` is not supposed to reside within `<table>` either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving the form element outside of the table.

```
<form name='entry' method='POST' action='solve.php'>    
    <table>
        <?php 
            include('grid.php');
        ?>
    </table>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit!'></input>           
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating invalid html: a `form` cannot be a direct child of a `table` element.

You should have the form encapsulate the table and move the button to below the table or put it in a row (and a column) below the grid inside the table:

```
<form name='entry' method='POST' action='solve.php'>  
    <table>  
        <?php 
            include('grid.php');
        ?>
    </table>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit!'></input>           
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply place the `<input type='submit' value='Submit!'></input>` inside another `<td></td>`

Answer (score 0):

You've put `form` inside of a `table` tag. You can't do that, it's in limbo. Do this.

```
<form>
    <table>
        ....
    </table>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap `<form>` and `<table>` like this:

```
<form name='entry' method='POST' action='solve.php'>    
    <table>
            <?php 
                include('grid.php');
            ?>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit!'></input>           

    </table>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just leave it outside the  table tag.

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit!'></input>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8N6hE/

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple example
you cant put a `<div>` in a `<p>`, so if you do that your browser will modify your code

you cant put a div (block element) in a p (inline element)

so if you do

```
<p>
    <div>
    </div>
</p>
```

your browser will change the code to

```
<p>
</p>
<div>
</div>
```

or

```
<p>
</p>
<div>
</div>
<p>
</p>
```

so here it's the same with form and table, you should start your `<form>` before starting your `<table>`

all this to say that if you generate invalid html code the browser will edit your code

Comment: if you explain your answer further as to why the browser does so, i'll vote you up.

Comment: The browser does this because it can't interpret invalid html code, so it haves to make it valid before interpretation...


if you try my example and look code with firebug you can see that firebug's code is different than html code

Comment: for example if you forget to close a </p> and if the browser didn't modify the code all the rest of the page would go into the <p> ...


So the browser closes the <p> for you, but sometimes browsers modifications change the display, like in this case

Comment: this does not explain anything. why cant a `<div>` reside in a `<p>`, but a `<h1>` can reside within a `<p>`

Comment: `<h1>` can't reside in a `<p>` try it and check with firebug, the browser closes the `<p>` before starting the `<h1>` and restarts a `<p>` after...
It's exactly the same that i told before with `<p>` and `<div>`

Comment: well, you're still not explaining why cant it reside within a `<p>`. Or if you're saying that nothing can reside within a `<p>`. You're merely stating that it is "invalid" html code. What makes it invalid? Why? And only under what circumstances does it become valid? I am not asking you a question, I'm teaching you how to answer.

Comment: I see that you've now added some explanations in. Thats better.

Comment: and just FYI, `<p>` is a block element. It's not an inline element.

Comment: yes sure sry, that's not what i wanted to say
`<p>` is a block element which must contain only inline elements

Comment: do you have more questions?